# Adding a particle onto the cube

Tags: materials, particles

**EDIT**
suppose that I have **two** blue keys as in the snippet added
in the top right corner at both, plane **and** sphere. So now **which one is used
if different *numbers* (say 100 and 1000) are entered for each Particle Setting** pertaining to plane and sphere, and hence more than one *Particle Settings* will exist for the 2 collections, so which one is used at the end with the blue cube (100 or 1000) ?

[image]

Previously I added cone and UV sphere onto the cube, but now I've failed
to add the small blue plane onto the cube. How can I do that ?

[image]

---

It is a bit better now but not **quiet** : some yellow surfaces appear but the **do not react** to the number nor to the length. Why ?

[image]

Comment: is the plane part of the same collection as the cone?

Comment: @moonboots I think it is! Please see the top right corner of the snippet.

Comment: The cube needs to be in a different collection than the particle objects.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: But the cone and the spehre are in the **same** collection and they are still on the surface of the cube as needed.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=ljawEnrk" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ljawEnrk/)

Comment: @moonboots Everything works fine, but I still do not know which item from the collection is **chosen** for the final result if there is more than one and also colliding **particle settings** and **rendering collection** could you please explain this to me yet ?

Comment: if you choose to render a collection, all the objects that are part of this collection will be rendered. For the rendering collection I'm not sure what you mean, maybe edit your initial question and add some images and explanations

Comment: @moonboots Please see the edit of my OQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first particle system works fine, you've chosen the cone as particle. For your second particle system though, you've chosen the collection called *Collection* as hair (*Particle > Render > Collection > Instance Collection*), but the emitter is part of this collection, which makes no sense. So you need to remove from *Collection* all the objects that are not supposed to be particles, i.e. *Camera, Light* and especially your emitter, *Cube*. Once done you'll see the every particles including the plane.

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to find the very first word in your answer: $Particle>Render> etc$ Could you send to me the collection removed as a `.blend` file ?

Comment: So that I can see how it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

When you render particles as a *collection*, you need a collection for it to use. In the example below, I have named my separate collection "Particles". You can see in the outliner that this group contains a sphere and a cone. When this collection ("Particles") is selected as the *Instanced Collection* in the Particle Settings, everything in that collection will be used as a particle. Thus, if you want the Plane to be a particle as well, you must put it in the same collection as the other particle objects (The collection that is being instanced). See below:

[image: Particles]